# apply recorded macro for all sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I recorded a macro for a specific sheet. But my problem is, each time I run this macro for another sheet, it is using the values of the sheet where I created the macro. But I want this macro works for any sheet. Here is what my code looks like:

```
Sub AutoGraph()
'
' AutoGraph Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+G
'
    Range("B:B,C:C").Select
    Range("C1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLineMarkers).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData source:=Range("SHEET1!$B:$B,SHEET1!$C:$C")
    Range("B:B,D:D,E1,E:E").Select
    Range("E1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData source:=Range( _
        "SHEET1!$B:$B,SHEET1!$D:$D,SHEET1!$E$1,SHEET1!$E:$E")
End Sub
```

Where SHEET1 is the sheet's name where I recorded macro. I think I need to change this with something common for all sheet, but couldn't find out the logic. I appreciate any comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `Sheet` hardcoded. This is why it is doing this.

One way to do this is to simply remove the references to Sheet1. This will cause Excel to default to whatever sheet you are currently on.

```
Sub AutoGraph()
'
' AutoGraph Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+G
'
    Range("B:B,C:C").Select
    Range("C1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLineMarkers).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData source:=Range("$B:$B,$C:$C")
    Range("B:B,D:D,E1,E:E").Select
    Range("E1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData source:=Range( _
        "$B:$B,$D:$D,$E$1,$E:$E")
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes this was exactly what I wanted and perfectly worked for me. Thanks enderland.